# When connecting to the PostgreSQL server, it returns an error (connection timeout expired)

Tags: postgresql, python-asyncio, fastapi

I will be very glad if you help to sort out this problem
Thank you in advance for your help

When connecting to the PostgreSQL server, it returns an error (connection timeout expired)

Working with FastAPI
When I log on to the created server and enter the password, it takes longer than usual to load it and, as a result, gives an error - connection timeout expired

Connection:

Alembic folder -

```
sqlalchemy.url = postgresql+asyncpg://%(DB_USER)s:%(DB_PASS)s@%(DB_HOST)s:%(DB_PORT)s/%(DB_NAME)s?async_fallback=True
```

Database folder:

```
DATABASE_URL = f"postgresql+asyncpg://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASS}@{DB_HOST}:{DB_PORT}/{DB_NAME}"
Base = declarative_base()
metadata = MetaData()
engine = create_async_engine(DATABASE_URL)
async_session_maker = async_sessionmaker(engine, expire_on_commit=False)
```

The .env folder:

```
    DB_HOST=localhost
    DB_PORT=5432
    DB_NAME=postgres
    DB_USER=postgres
    DB_PASS=XXXXX
```

Everything is connected correctly in pgAdmin, because it worked before that.

What I did myself:

Installed a standard web socket
Updated the database to 7.1
Checked the logs

Comment: A network problem (firewall etc.), quite unrelated to programming.